# How does Spensa recognise these smells?

Tags: skyward

In *Starsight*, the second *Skyward* novel, Spensa meets an alien called Vapor - a member of the figment race, who are invisible, and identifiable only through smell. Vapor's smell appears to change based on her emotions, with "cinnamon" and "lemons" being the most common.

But Spensa comes from a planet with little to no agriculture, and has spent most of her life eating bland algae strips. I remember a small area of farming being mentioned in the first novel, but not a description of what was grown there - it seems unlikely it was lemons and cinnamon, rather than, say, potatoes or wheat.

How does Spensa recognise smells given off by Vapor, such as lemon or cinnamon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's ever explicitly stated how Spensa knows those scents, but since she obviously does, a couple of explanations come to mind.

1. You mentioned the small farming area, but in Skyward, it specifically stated that there's an orchard.

> We approached the base, a group of tall, stern buildings surrounded by a wall. Right outside it, the farms gave way to an actual orchard. I stopped on the walkway, and found myself gaping again. I’d seen these trees from a distance, but up close they seemed enormous. Almost three meters tall!

To me, orchard implies fruit trees, so maybe they grew lemons there.

2. In Starsight, when Spensa mentions the lemon scent, she sometimes associates the lemon scent with cleaning solutions

> We turned down another hallway, and I was hit with the scent of lemons. Maybe a cleaning crew had been through recently?

It's possible that some cleaning products on Detritus were lemon scented and if she hadn't smelled an actual lemon, learned the smell from that.

3. The cinnamon smell is tougher, but in Skyward, the cadets mention dessert often. The only specific dessert mentioned that I can find is chocolate cake, but cinnamon is a common dessert ingredient, so it's possible she had cinnamon at the base at some point.